# setTimeout Javascript 'Timer'

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```js
let doit = (from, to) => {
  let a = setTimeout(doit, 500, ++from);
  console.table(from);
  if (from === to) {
    clearTimeout(a)
  }
};

 doit(6, 13);
```

Write a printNumbers(from, to) function that prints a number every second,
starting from from and ending with to .
Can you describe me why this timer is not stopping?
Can you answer with comments please.

Comment: Because you'd also need to pass `to` through to the "recursive" call…?

Comment: you need to look how setTimeout works `function[, delay, arg1, arg2,` A simple `console.log(from, to)` should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Well you closed a question that could be answered with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't stop because you're not passing `to` through to the recursive call. You're only passing `++from`. This would be rather obvious if you logged both values:

```js
let doit = (from, to) => {
  let a = setTimeout(doit, 500, ++from);
  console.log(from, to);
  if (from === to) {
    clearTimeout(a)
  }
};

 doit(6, 13);
```

The solution is to also pass `to`:

```js
let doit = (from, to) => {
  let a = setTimeout(doit, 500, ++from, to); // 
  console.log(from, to);
  if (from === to) {
    clearTimeout(a)
  }
};

 doit(6, 13);
```